# Does not want to wait for animation to complete

Tags: android

I have a button A which translates from position X to position Y. I have put a `setAnimationlistner` on the button such that it becomes invisible after the animation ends (unsing on `AnimationEnd`).

There is another button B if clicked makes the previous button A visible.
If I wait for the animation to complete and click button B, everything works fine. But if I click button B during animation, button A doesn't become visible.
How to solve this problem?

P.S- I don't want to disable button B during Animation. I am searching for a workaround

My program is as follows-

```
package com.example.tes2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn1,btn2;
    Animation translateAnimation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                translateAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 500);
                translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                translateAnimation.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
                translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
                translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new   AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        btn1.setClickable(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        btn1.clearAnimation();
                        btn1.setClickable(true);
                        btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                btn1.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: there is a bug in your code: the code we have never seen

Comment: Please post your code